# Carbon Nanotube Modeling

Tags: material-science, simulations, geometry, nanoscience

In various references, we see the construction of unit cells of carbon nanotubes from chiral and translational vectors.

[image]

The chiral vector is given as:

$$\vec C_h = n\vec a_1 + m\vec a_2$$

While the translational vector is given by:

$$\vec T = t_1\vec a_1 + t_2\vec a_2$$

Clearly, $\vec C_h$ and $\vec T$ must be orthogonal, hence $\vec C_h \cdot \vec T = 0$. In the literature, it always appears that $t_1 = \displaystyle\frac{2m+n}{d_R}$ and $t_2 = -\displaystyle\frac{2n+m}{d_R}$, where $d_R=\mathrm{gcd}(2m+n,2n-m)$.

My questions are, how to deduce this? And how does this relate to the fact that the translational vector can determine the size of the unit cell?

I managed to replicate this idea for a hexagonal lattice, similar to graphene.

For a rectangular lattice, I successfully reproduced the chiral vector, but I haven't yet managed to understand or reproduce the translational vector (not even for CNTs, actually).

Comment: If I do $C_h \cdot T$ with the $t_1$ and $t_2$ written in terms of $m$ and $n
$, I get $(n^2-m^2)/d_R$, which is $0$ only if $n = \pm m$.